# Sign in with Apple (iOS App + Backend verification) API returns error "invalid_client"

Tags: ios, oauth, jwt, apple-id, sign-in-with-apple

I'm trying to implement **Sign In with Apple** with an iOS app and a backend. The goal is this:

1. The User signs in on the iOS app
2. After a positive response the app calls an endpoint on the backend and hands over the `authorizationCode`
3. The backend now needs to verify the `authorizationCode` with another call to apple's server.

Here I'm confused. In order to make this call, the backend needs to provide a bunch of parameters:

**URL**

```
https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token
```

**Query Parameters**

```
client_id     = com.mycompany.appname
client_secret = ...
code          = ... // `authorizationCode` from the signin in the iOS app
grant_type    = authorization_code
```

I've generated a `JWT` for the `client_secret`:

**JWT Properties**

```
header:
    kid: <key id, created on Apple Dev Portal>
claims:
    iss: <team id>
    iat: <current timestamp>
    exp: <current timestamp + 180 days>
    aud: "https://appleid.apple.com"
    sub: "com.mycompany.appname"
```

Yesterday I've created two keys for two apps (A and B) on the Dev Portal, used it to generate secrets and today app A worked and I've got a positive response:

**Positive response**

```
{
    "access_token" : "a1e64327924yt49f5937d643e25a48b81.0.mxwz.GN9TjJIJ5_4dR6WjbZoVNw",
    "token_type" : "Bearer", 
    "expires_in" : 3600, 
    "refresh_token" : "rca76d9ebta644fde9edba269c61eeb41.0.mxwz.sMDUlXnnLLUOu2z0WlABoQ", 
    "id_token" : "eyJraWQiOiJBSURPUEsxIcccYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2FwcGxlaWQuYXBwbGUuY29tIiwiYXVkIjoiZGUudHJ1ZmZscy5hcHBsZS1zaWduaW4tdGVzdCIsImV4cCI6MTU2NzcwMDI0MiwiaWF0IjoxNTY3Njk5NjQyLCJzdWaaaiIwMDA3NjkuYWY3NDdjMTlmZGRmNDJhNjhhYmFkZjhlNTQ1MmY3NjAuMjIwNSIsImF0X2hhc2giOiJrVThQTkZOUHYxS0RGUEtMT2hIY213IiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTY3Njk5NjM5fQ.g3JD2MDGZ6wiVS9VMHpj24ER0XqJlunatmqpE7sRarMkhMHMTk7j8gty1lpqVBC6Z8L5CZuewdzLuJ5Odrd3_c1cX7gparTQE4jCyvyTACCPKHXReTC2hGRIEnAogcxv6HDWrtZgb3ENhoGhZW778d70DUdd-e4KKiAvzLOse-endHr51PaR1gv-cHPcwnm3NQZ144I-xhpU5TD9VQJ9IgLQvZGZ8fi8SOcu6rrk5ZOr0mpt0NbJNGYgH5-8iuSxo18QBWZDXoEGNsa4kS5GDkq5Cekxt7JsJFc_L1Np94giXhpbYHqhcO1pZSGFrJVaMvMMftZfuS_T3sh2yCqkcA"
}
```

B, however, still doesn't work. Today I revoked the key for A and created a new one and now it doesn't work anymore with the new one, but still with the old one, even though I deleted it on the Dev Portal. I'm so confused.

**Response Error**:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

I wonder if Apple needs some time indexing or something like that. I just want to understand how this works.

Comment: what’s the client id you used in the validate request?

Comment: @stamaimer the bundle id of my ios app

Answer (score 11):

I was scratching my head quite a bit on how to validate the Sign In with Apple from the iOS app on the server side and couldn't find too much documentation about it.

I'll leave my implementation in nodeJS here in case it helps anyone; I actually followed the approach outlined [here](https://blog.curtisherbert.com/so-theyve-signed-in-with-apple-now-what/) by Curtis Herbert

1. From the iOS app you get an ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential which includes, among other details, a user (id), an email, and an identityToken (short lived JWT)
2. On the server side you can use Apple Json Web Keys available in https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys to generate a public key.

```
    {
      "keys": [
        {
          "kty": "RSA",
          "kid": "86D88Kf",
          "use": "sig",
          "alg": "RS256",
          "n": "iGaLqP6y-SJCCBq5Hv6pGDbG_SQ11MNjH7rWHcCFYz4hGwHC4lcSurTlV8u3avoVNM8jXevG1Iu1SY11qInqUvjJur--hghr1b56OPJu6H1iKulSxGjEIyDP6c5BdE1uwprYyr4IO9th8fOwCPygjLFrh44XEGbDIFeImwvBAGOhmMB2AD1n1KviyNsH0bEB7phQtiLk-ILjv1bORSRl8AK677-1T8isGfHKXGZ_ZGtStDe7Lu0Ihp8zoUt59kx2o9uWpROkzF56ypresiIl4WprClRCjz8x6cPZXU2qNWhu71TQvUFwvIvbkE1oYaJMb0jcOTmBRZA2QuYw-zHLwQ",
          "e": "AQAB"
        },
        {
          "kty": "RSA",
          "kid": "eXaunmL",
          "use": "sig",
          "alg": "RS256",
          "n": "4dGQ7bQK8LgILOdLsYzfZjkEAoQeVC_aqyc8GC6RX7dq_KvRAQAWPvkam8VQv4GK5T4ogklEKEvj5ISBamdDNq1n52TpxQwI2EqxSk7I9fKPKhRt4F8-2yETlYvye-2s6NeWJim0KBtOVrk0gWvEDgd6WOqJl_yt5WBISvILNyVg1qAAM8JeX6dRPosahRVDjA52G2X-Tip84wqwyRpUlq2ybzcLh3zyhCitBOebiRWDQfG26EH9lTlJhll-p_Dg8vAXxJLIJ4SNLcqgFeZe4OfHLgdzMvxXZJnPp_VgmkcpUdRotazKZumj6dBPcXI_XID4Z4Z3OM1KrZPJNdUhxw",
          "e": "AQAB"
        }
      ]
    }
```

3. Finally, using the public key you can verify the identityToken to make sure it was generated by Apple. I used the library [jose](https://github.com/panva/jose) for it

```
    const axios = require('axios').default;
    const jose = require('jose')
    const {
      JWKS,  // JSON Web Key Set (JWKS)
      JWT,   // JSON Web Token (JWT)
      errors // errors utilized by jose
    } = jose    
    axios.get('https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys')
                .then(function (response) {
                    // handle success
                    const key = jose.JWKS.asKeyStore(response.data);
                    const verified = jose.JWT.verify(identityToken, key);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error);
                })
                .then(function () {
                    // always executed
                });
```

At the end you get a an object with the same structure as if you were decoding the JWT (identityToken) in which you can validate that;

- iss is https://appleid.apple.com
- aud is your app Bundle ID
- email and sub match your ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential values

```
    {
            "iss": "https://appleid.apple.com",
            "aud": "BundleID",
            "sub": "credential.user",
            "email": "credential.email",
        }
```

Comment: Awesome explanation! Just a question @David: do you do this check for login also, or just for registration?

Comment: Thanks @AlexBartiş, I'm still working on this but I'm thinking, from that point onward, on handling access tokens myself to keep my users logged in. That being said, I'll check the  Apple ID session with getCredentialState(forUserID:completion:) on every app open. If they logout and log back in with the Apple ID I'll check the identityToken again. What are your thoughts around this?

Comment: yup, client side validation based on Apples API works, but I'm also thinking to the the identity token validation at each login also. My idea is that apple provides the user email only the first time the user registers. I can grab it from the payload after token validation and send it back on login successful so that my device can update it in it;s storage. If the user reinstalls the app and I lose the email from the device, there's no other way of getting it back.

Answer (score 10):

There are several reasons why it could happen:

1. `client_id` for **web** should be **Service id**. For **apps** it should be **App bundle id**. (Even if you use native apple dialog get `code` and later pass it to a webserver and then use it to request token API.) `sub` in JWT call should be the same as `client_id`.
   [See the answer there Apple forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/365530#36553)
2. Your JWT library does not support encryption required by Apple sign-in. They use the JWT standard for this, using an elliptic curve algorithm with a P-256 curve and SHA256 hash. In other words, they use the ES256 JWT algorithm. Some JWT libraries don’t support elliptic curve methods, so make sure yours does before you start trying this out. [ES256 and invalid_client](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/issues/251)
3. Dates in token. Try to set the following

> ```
>  expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(2), // expiry can be a maximum of 6 months
>  issuedAt: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
>  notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1),
> ```

It failed with invalid_client on my webserver, since Apple considered it as a certificate from the future, when I had:

```
 expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5), // expiry can be a maximum of 6 months
 issuedAt: DateTime.UtcNow,
 notBefore: DateTime.UtcNow,
```

4. It's also important to specify the **User-Agent** header when you call the token API. It's also worth mentioning that curl can throw this error, while it will work fine when you call it from a web server.
5. Make sure you are setting the correct `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` header instead of `Content-Type: application/json` that some libraries like [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) set by default.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with invalid_client, what kind of value did you provide for the user agent header?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda you can put any value there. I have my app name there.

Comment: Thanks, still can't get this thing to work. I am pretty certain my token (secret) is created correctly, did you do anything else in the dev console other than creating the key for Apple Sign in and attaching it to a bundle identifier?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda didn't have problems with console. I also did domain verification, not quite sure if it's important.

Answer (score 1):

Your native APP ID is your bundle ID prefixed with your team ID, seperated by a dot.

"The Apple App ID is a two part string used to identify one or more apps. Specifically, the Apple app ID is your team ID and bundle ID joined with a period, for [example](https://support.bitly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020990411-Application-IDs-and-where-to-find-them): 1A234H7ABC.com.yourdomain.YourApp."

I'm having the same issue getting this to work however.

Comment: I've been using the bundle id directly (without the team Id) to some success. This is from an app, not from the web.

Comment: The identifier (App ID or Services ID) for your app. The identifier must not include your Team ID, to help mitigate sensitive data exposure to the end user. This parameter is required for both authorization code and refresh token validation requests. ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/generate_and_validate_tokens

Answer (score 1):

If anybody want to use it in java backend, here is the valid code with nimbus-jose-jwt java [lib](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/download)

```
var publicKeys = JWKSet.load(new URL("https://appleid.apple.com/auth/keys"));

    publicKeys.getKeys().forEach(jwk -> {
        try {
            System.out.println(JWSObject.parse(appleIdentityToken)
                    .verify(new RSASSAVerifier(jwk.toRSAKey())));
        } catch (JOSEException | ParseException joseException) {
            joseException.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

We get "invalid client" when there is problem in your key or "sub" when verifying authorization code with ES256. Use the below code and your problem will be solved, as I have solved my problem .

Code :

```
private static CngKey GetPrivateKey()
    {
        using (var reader = File.OpenText(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key2"].ToString()))  //put your key's path  like C:\ABC.p8
        {
            var ecPrivateKeyParameters = (ECPrivateKeyParameters)new PemReader(reader).ReadObject();
            var x = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineXCoord.GetEncoded();
            var y = ecPrivateKeyParameters.Parameters.G.AffineYCoord.GetEncoded();
            var d = ecPrivateKeyParameters.D.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
            return EccKey.New(x, y, d);
        }
    }
   var utc0 = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    var issueTime = DateTime.Now;

    var iat = (int)issueTime.Subtract(utc0).TotalSeconds;
    var exp = (int)issueTime.AddMinutes(55).Subtract(utc0).TotalSeconds;
    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "sub", "com.xyzttt" },  // you registered app 
        { "aud", "https://appleid.apple.com"},
        { "iss", "ABCDEFGHttt" },  //Team id 
        { "exp", exp },   }, //current time + @@@@ 
        { "iat", iat } } // current time
    };
    var extraHeader = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
          { "alg", "ES256" },
          { "kid", "5ABCDEFGH123tt21"}, //key id
    };
    var sb = GetPrivateKey(); 

    var ecdsa = new ECDsaCng(sb);

    byte[] headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(extraHeader, Formatting.None));
    byte[] claimsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, Formatting.None));


    var Rpayload = Base64UrlEncode(headerBytes) + "." + Base64UrlEncode(claimsBytes);
    var signature = ecdsa.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Rpayload), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
    var data = Base64UrlEncode(signature);
    string token = Rpayload + "." + data;
   
    return token;
```

Answer (score 0):

For folks still struggling with this: **I had to wait 48h after creating my first key** for it to be picked up by Apple servers. For the last two days I've been trying every single solution I could find on-line, thinking that I made a mistake somewhere. Nope.. what fixed it was time (or somebody at apple modifying something on their end). I invoked exactly the same curl request 10 minutes ago and now, getting two different responses from apple's api. EXACTLY the same request (including all parameters).

- 10 minutes ago:  {"error":"invalid_client" }
- 1 minute ago: {"error":"invalid_grant"}    (yes!!!)
- now: success (after updating "code" to a fresh authorizationCode generated by my iOS app)

Just be patient. Wait for 48h after creating your first key at https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/authkeys/list