# "Invalid_client" error getting at time of Sign in with Apple

Tags: ios, node.js, express, jwt, apple-sign-in

I'm facing issues for sign in with the apple. I go through many blogs and official documentation but nothing works.

The flow of my application is the same as mentioned in the documentation: Application will send authorization code to the backend server, backend server generates a client secret and it will send it to the apple server in order to get access_token.

Getting the same response every time: 
`response: {"error: "invalid_client"}`

So here is my code:

**Generating client_secret**

used jsonwebtoken package.

```
let client_secret = jwt.sign({}, privateToken, {
    algorithm: 'ES256',
    expiresIn: 1578513833,
    audience: "https://appleid.apple.com",
    subject: process.env.APPLE_CLIENT_ID,
    issuer: process.env.ISS,
    keyid: process.env.KID
});
```

**Payload to send to apple server**

```
let body = {
  client_id: process.env.APPLE_CLIENT_ID,
  client_secret: client_secret,
  code: authorize_code,
  grant_type: 'authorization_code'
}
```

**Request to apple server**

```
let appleResponse = await axios.post(
  'https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token',
  queryString.stringify(body), {
  headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }
});
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this error.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it expects the content in a query string and not a JSON payload?

Comment: I think it will take a JSON payload. I have tried both to check. but none of them work. @DanielSchroederDev

Comment: Where is user-agent header? It's a required parameter.

Comment: Check out my answer, I collected troubleshooter for invalid_client error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242658/1099716

Comment: Solved!! The error is occurred because of the expiry date. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For the last 3 days, I was getting the same error "invalid_client" from the API

Turns out that I needed to encode the HttpBody using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26365148/13939053) extension

**Note:** for you, there might be another reasons for the error, make sure to sign valid JWT.